# Does a set of eigenvalues in QM correspond to a random variable in statistics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistics

In quantum mechanics the possible outcomes of a measurement of a quantity corresponding to a linear hermitian operator $A$ are only the eigenvalues $a_i$ of $A$ (see e.g. http://wwwitp.physik.tu-berlin.de/brandes/public_html/qm/umist_qm/node65.html). The expectation value of $A$ is computed as
$$
\langle A \rangle_\psi = \sum_j a_j |\langle \psi | \phi_j \rangle|^2
$$
where $|\langle \psi | \phi_j \rangle|^2$ is called the transition probability (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation_value_(quantum_mechanics)).

In statistics a random variable $X$ is said to be a set of possible values $x_i$ from a random experiment (see e.g. https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/random-variables.html). The expected value of $X$ is computed as
$$
\operatorname{E}[X] = \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i\, p_i,
$$
where $p_i$ are the probabilities of the $x_i$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value).

So can one say, that the set of expectation values $\{a_j\}$ with transition probabilities $|\langle \psi | \phi_j \rangle|^2$ in QM corresponds to a random variable $X = \{x_i\}$ with probabilities $p_i$ in statistics?

Comment: I'm not sure how this is different from [your other question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/232968/50583), and how this is not also answered by the [duplicate](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/116595/50583) linked there. "Having an eigenvalue $\phi_j$" is precisely the type of proposition that ValterMoretti considers in his answer.

Comment: The term "eigenvalue" does not appear in the answer of ValterMoretti you link to, so I think my question is different.

Comment: Look at the proposition $P$: *"The $x$-value of the spin is $1/2$"* - that *is* the statement that the observable $\sigma_x$ takes a certain eigenvalue. He doesn't explicitly *say* it, but most propositions you will consider in practice are of course statements about the values of observables, and hence eigenvalues.

Comment: But ValterMoretti is talking about measurements of two observables (which as I understand don't commute in QM in general). That is not what I'm asking about. My question is much simpler and only concerns the measurement of a single observable.

Comment: If you only have one observable, then everything commutes (the projectors onto the eigenspaces commute because their product is zero), and you indeed get back classical/commutative probability. I maintain this is all in the answer - you just have to *read* it.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked this clear statement in the wall of text by Moretti: "As a matter of fact, a maximal set of pairwise commuting projectors has formal properties identical to those of classical logic: is a Boolean σ-algebra."