Does the collapse axiom predict non-physical states in the case of measurement of continuous-spectrum quantities?
Let us assume a continuous wave function.
Suppose we make a measurement of the position of the particle and obtain as a result the interval $(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)$.  $\delta>0$ stays for the accuracy of the instrument.
If I understand correctly, following the measurement, the collapse axiom (Luders-von Neumann's axiom) predicts that the new wave function (up to normalization) is the same as the previous function within the interval and is zero outside the interval (See for example Valter Moretti's answer  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/247521).
So the wave function is discontinuous at the extremes of the interval, at the two points $x_0-\delta$ and $x_0+\delta$.
The discontinuous functions have the trouble that the expectation value of the kinetic energy is infinite (See for example Luboš Motl's answer  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38183), so it is a non-physical state.
What is the origin of this apparent contradiction?
Does the collapse axiom predict non-physical states in the case of continuous-spectrum measurement?
Is it possible to predict a valid shape of the wave function after the collapse?

Since my name directly appears in the question, I think that I should try to answer, also because I substantially changed some ideas about some of these issues in the last years.
First of all, the right approach when considering the measurement problem is the one of "quantum measurement theory" based on POVMs (Positive Operator Valued Measures), Kraus decompositions and, more generally, the notion of quantum measurement scheme.
An important theoretical reference is the book by P. Busch and collaborators "Quantum Measurement".
When dealing with observables -- in the general sense either described in terms of POVMs or PVMs (Projection-Valued- Measures, i.e. selfadjoint operators)-- which attain discrete values, then the Lueders-vonNeumann postulate projection can be assumed among a plethora of other possibilities however.
Instead, when the values are continuous, the projection postulate is physically untenable for many reasons  (failure of additivity of the post-measurement state, Ozawa theorem, ...).
In this case, but also in the general case, the post-measurement state is described by a suitable measurement scheme.
There are infinitely many measurement schemes for a given observable (also if described by a PVM, i.e. a selfadjoint operator). In general, the post-measurement state turns out to be mixed even if the pre-measurement state is pure.
So, assigning an observable in terms of a POVM or a selfadjoint operator (PVM) says nothing about the post-measurement state associated with an outcome and a pre-measurement state.
If we make discrete a continuous observable by brute force, using approximations, then there are processes which agree with the projection postulate state.
However, even making discrete some observables like the non-relativistic position, e.g., by using a sequence of contiguous instruments each capable of measuring a segment $I_n:= (x_n-\delta, x_n+\delta]$, it is difficult to assert that $\psi_n= \chi_{I_n}(x) \psi(x)$ is the post-measurement state if $I_n$ is the outcome for the pre-measurement state $\psi$.
That is because $\psi_n$ has infinite energy or suffers from some similar pathologies. There are better descriptions of measurement schemes for the position observable, which take advantage of probe particles with their own wavefunctions, which, in turn,  enter the description of the post-measurement state.
A similar measurement procedure already appears in von Neumann's book about mathematical foundations of QM.
ADDENDUM. The projection postulate can be demonstrated under some apparently weak hypotheses.
Suppose that $P(\Delta)$ is an orthogonal projector of a spectral measure of an observable, described as a selfadjoint operator. Consider another elementary fact (Yes-No): an orthogonal projector  $Q$ such that $Q\leq P(\Delta)$. Notice that $Q\leq P(\Delta)$ is equivalent to $QP(\Delta)=P(\Delta)Q= Q$, thus, according with the standard interpretation
(i) $Q$ and $P(\Delta)$ are compatible,
(ii) $Q$ implies $P(\Delta)$.
One, therefore, aspects that we can simultaneously measure $Q$ and $P(\Delta)$ and that the conditional probability laws hold true since these observables are compatible: if we measure $P(\Delta)$ and $Q$ on the initial state $\psi$, with obvious meaning
$${\cal P}_\psi( Q| P(\Delta)  ) {\cal P}_\psi(P(\Delta)) = {\cal P}_\psi (P(\Delta) \wedge Q) = {\cal P}_\psi(Q)\tag{1}\label{eq:1}.$$
It is not difficult to prove that if the family of the $Q$ is sufficiently large, for instance  it includes the  set of one-dimensional projectors  $|\psi_n \rangle\langle \psi_n|$ where $\{\psi_n\}$ is a Hilbert basis of the projection space of $P(\Delta)$, then the only possibility for the post-measurement state after the outcome $\Delta$ of the observable of $P(\Delta)$ is the one predicted by the projection postulate:
$$P(\Delta)\psi\:,$$
if the initial state was $\psi$.
Since the post-measurement state is not necessarily of that form, especially if $\Delta$ is a subset of a continuous set, we must conclude that $\eqref{eq:1}$ is not valid. The standard axioms of classical conditional probability are not necessarily valid even when dealing with compatible observables.

Many many thanks Valter for the detailed explanation that clarifies this rather complex issue. So I deduce that, following the measurement that returns an interval, it is not possible to predict a priori univocally what the new wave function is. I understand that to find the new wave function it is necessary to make further hypotheses that can lead to different wave functions. Did I understand correctly?

Yes, one should also provide a detailed description of the measurement procedure and only in some cases the post measurement state agrees with the projection postulate (it is easy to arrange  these procedures for discrete spectra). In general the only choice of the observable says nothing about the relation between the premeasurment state and the post measurement state when the outcome is known.

Regardless of the exact shape of the new wave function,
can we at least say that the new wave function is zero outside the found interval?

It depends on the instrument. It is possible to prove that in relativistic theory the answer is always negative.

Hi Valter, nice answer. I had time to read about these issues a bit. Let me ask if I understood you correctly: What you describe here is the (mathematical/QM) notion of an instrument, correct? And what you say is that there are many instruments corresponding to the same observable/POVM; the post-measurement state however depends explicitly on the instrument (and not only on the POVM), reflecting the fact that different experimental measurements (of the same physical quantity) can perturb/change the quantum state in a different manner. (?)

Yes you have understood well. Furthermore, the fact that repeating (immediately after) a measurement one gets the same result  may be false and it is always false for continuous observables.  However, the postulate projection can be demostrated under some hypotheses (there is a theorem by Luders) when assuming the classical laws of conditional probability for compatible observables. The failure of it implies in particular that the laws of conditional probability may be non-classical also dealing with compatible observables: or better that these laws  are empirical.

That fact is remarkable to me.

Thanks for the reply and the addendum in your answer. Yes, this is interesting indeed.

Hi @ValterMoretti. Let's suppose we use a certain instrument (probe) to measure the quantity x. Let's suppose that our instrument analyzes exclusively the interval $(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)$ and that as a result it has only two outcomes: the particle "is found" (TRUE) or "is not found" (FALSE) in the interval.
So, if a first measurement provides the result TRUE, isn't it certain that a second sudden measurement provides TRUE again?

That is a very idealised situation, everything concurs to the answer: yes. However in practice, such idealized situations do not exist and everything depends on the used instrument.

Suppose you have an electron interacting with a Geiger counter. There is a description of what is happening in terms of some quantum field theory such as QED. Those equations describe what is happening and make predictions about correlations among observables and that sort of thing. I looked in the index of the following five textbooks on QFT and collapse didn't appear in the index in any of them:
"A modern introduction to quantum field theory" by Maggiore
"Quantum field theory for the gifted amateur" by Lancaster and Blundell
"Quantum field theory in a nutshell" by Zee
"Quantum theory of fields, Volume I: Foundations" by Weinberg
"The conceptual framework of quantum field theory" by Duncan
Collapse doesn't appear in any of these books because it is incompatible with the equations of motion of quantum theory. It appears only in books that abstract away from those equations of motion. A real measurement is an interaction that takes place according to those equations of motion and produces a record of some attribute of a system. When you describe a measurement according to the actual laws of physics that have survived testing in reality what happens is that having information copied out of a record suppresses interference between some selected set of roughly orthonormal states - decoherence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
You don't measure a function that cuts of sharply at the ends of an interval because that is incompatible with real physics. In some situations collapse might be an adequate approximation for the purposes of making a prediction but many real measurements can't be treated that way:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.05973
If you want to predict and understand what will happen in a real measurement according to quantum theory you have to use quantum theory not unphysical rules of thumb like collapse.

Thanks for the reply, alanf. What you say is clear, in fact I understood that the collapse axiom can be used exclusively when the measuring instrument is of a macroscopic type, that is, the instrument is a classical and not quantum apparatus unlike the observed system, which for example can be the observed quantum particle. So I think that the collapse axiom cannot be used in QFT.
