# Axiomatic Treatment of Quantum Probability Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability, foundations

Define quantum probability theory to be an axiomatic mathematical theory which appropriately generalizes classical (Kolmogorov) probability theory to provide the precise probabilistic framework underlying the empirical results and established theory of quantum mechanics.

Does such a quantum probability theory exist? I would appreciate references if the answer is "yes".

Comment: the postulates of quantum mechanics can be seen here  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html

Comment: @annav What does this have anything to do with the question asked?

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/116595/why-is-the-application-of-probability-in-quantum-mechanics-fundamentally-differe) if not duplicate.

Comment: @SillyGoose if you read the link, the postulates of QM are stated in the second paragraph which lead to the theory you are asking for

Comment: @annav you are completely misunderstanding the question. Silly Goose already understands basic quantum mechanics and its postulates. The problem is of the _logic._ You can check the link by Tobias for a taste of what kind of answer is being sought.